# show/hide picture box in form1 from another form2

Tags: c#

i have button1 in form1 when click it then it should hide picturebox in form2

i'm try to make a button in form2 contain

```
picturebox1.hide();
```

and call this button from form1 by

```
new form1().button1.PerformClick();
```

also i **trying** this

```
            new home().pictureBox1.Show();
```

but not work

so that i'm ask if there is another way to show/hide picturebox in other form ?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, don't try to invoke buttons across the forms.  Instead, just have a method on the form which does what you want:

```
public void HidePicture()
{
    picturebox1.hide();
}
```

Basically separate your logic from your UI inputs invoking that logic.

But aside from that, and focusing on the main issue you're facing, consider the logic of what's happening here:

```
new form1().HidePicture();
```

This would successfully hide the picture, but it's hiding it on *a new form* that *isn't being displayed*.  This creates an entirely new form:

```
new form1()
```

It *doesn't* reference whatever instance of `form1` is already on your screen.  You need to reference that.  How are these forms related?  Does `form1` launch an instance of `form2` somewhere?  If so, then `form2` needs to hold a reference back to the form that launched it.  For example, if you have this on `form2`:

```
private form1 ParentForm { get; set; }

public form2(form1 parent)
{
    this.ParentForm = parent;
}
```

Then when you originally create your instance of `form2` to show to the user, you'd pass that reference:

```
var childForm = new form2(this);
childForm.Show();
```

Now that instance of `form2` has a reference to the instance of `form1` which created it.  From there you can invoke the method on that instance:

```
this.ParentForm.HidePicture();
```

However your forms are set up, whichever forms spawn other forms, you'd just need to keep references to the form instances that are dependencies of other form instances.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to make the control static.